# Jackson property order based on field value

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, jackson-databind

I am trying to serialise and deserialise a `Java` class using `Jackson` and the `JsonPropertyOrder` depends on the value of the `version` field in the class. If `version = 1`, I want order to be `{"start1", "start2"}`, if `version = 2`, order should be `{"end1", "end2"}`.
I have below class:

```
 @Builder
 @Value
 @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@JsonCreator))
 @JsonPropertyOrder(custom property order depending on version field)
 public class ClassA {

   @NonNull Integer version;

   @NonNull String start1;

   @NonNull String start2;

   @NonNull String end1;

   @NonNull String end2;
}
```

How can I define the `JsonPropertyOrder` based on version on runtime. If I should use a custom `Deserializer`, I cannot figure out how exactly it should be implemented and set with the `ObjectMapper`.

This is the code for deserialisation:

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();//have initialzed this as a bean
String jsonStr = "{\"version\":1, \"startLat\":\"47.6812\", \"startLng\":\"-122.3268\", \"endLat\":\"47.6074\", \"endLng\":\"-122.3377\"}";
ClassA objA = null;
    try {
        objA = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, ClassA.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error deserializing the string", jsonStr, e);
    }
return objA;
```

**EDIT: I missed an imp part. The property order here matters because the serialised string might not have the field names. Is that possible to do?
So the str `[1, "47.6812", "-122.3268"]` will need to be deserialised to the fields version, `start1`, `start2`.

Comment: what effect json order makes?

Comment: I have a version that uses a particular json order right now and I need to support another version in the future that will have a different order. So depending on the version the order will change.

Comment: ya but still json order doesn't matter while consuming it please cross check once

Comment: I guess I meant the same order will apply in serialization also. So in version 1, a particular order was used for serialization, then during deserialization, depending on the version, it should map the fields correctly. basically depending on the version, I want to set the @JsonPropertyOrder for ser/deserialization

Comment: So, you have three different possible `JSON` payloads: 1. `{"version":1, "startLat":"47.6812", "startLng":"-122.3268", "endLat":"47.6074", "endLng":"-122.3377"}`, 2. `{"version":1, "startLat":"47.6812", "startLng":"-122.3268"}` and 3. `{"version":2, "endLat":"47.6074", "endLng":"-122.3377"}`. Could you confirm? This is not a valid `JSON`: `{1, "47.6812", "-122.3268"}` but this is `[1, "47.6812", "-122.3268"]`. Object always must have property. Array from other side can store objects and primitives without property name. So, you need to support all 4 kind of payloads or only last?

Comment: @MichałZiober Sorry my bad. I need to support the last payload where json does not have the field names and need to do it using jackson.

Answer (score 0):

If these properties are exclusive why do not create more concise `POJO` by removing two of them? You can use knowledge that `1` means something different than `2` by introducing some `isMethod`-es or `Enum`. To serialise class as `JSON array` you need to use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)` annotation. To deserialise you can use `3-arg` constructor with `@JsonCreator` and `@JsonProperty` annotations. Properties are `final`. All together makes - class is well implemented. See example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ClassA classA1 = new ClassA(1, "Start_1", "Start_2");
        ClassA classA2 = new ClassA(2, "End_1", "End_2");

        String json1 = mapper.writeValueAsString(classA1);
        String json2 = mapper.writeValueAsString(classA2);

        System.out.println(json1);
        System.out.println(json2);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json1, ClassA.class));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json2, ClassA.class));
    }
}

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
class ClassA {

    private final Integer version;

    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;

    @JsonCreator
    public ClassA(@JsonProperty("version") Integer version,
                  @JsonProperty("start1") String value1,
                  @JsonProperty("start2") String value2) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(version);
        if (!(version == 1 || version == 2)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Version is not supported!");
        }
        this.version = version;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isStart() {
        return version == 1;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isEnd() {
        return version == 2;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassA{" +
                "version=" + version +
                ", value1='" + value1 + '\'' +
                ", value2='" + value2 + '\'' +
                ", isEnd()='" + isEnd() + '\'' +
                ", isStart()='" + isStart() + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[1,"Start_1","Start_2"]
[2,"End_1","End_2"]
ClassA{version=1, value1='Start_1', value2='Start_2', isEnd()='false', isStart()='true'}
ClassA{version=2, value1='End_1', value2='End_2', isEnd()='true', isStart()='false'}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michal Ziober !!